# Toolbar animateLayoutChanges strange behavior

Tags: android

I set animateLayoutChanges=true in my code, to animate the options item I have in my fragments.

When I open the PreferenceFragment I enable the up navigation icon, then I disable it when I close it, but it behaves in a strange way, leaving a sort of padding to the left of the title, where the NavigationIcon was.

Here's a gif showing what's happening:

[image: img]

Do you guy's have any idea on why is this happening?
I searched far and wide on the internet, but found nothing.

Is there any workaround to animate these items in the same way?
Thanks.

Comment: Have you managed to solve this issue?

Answer (score 3):

Remark: I know this thread in more than a year long but a lot of people still stumble on this problem.

It took me good few hours to finally dig into this problem and solution is actually relatively easy.

### The Scenario

When you call ActionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled() or Toolbar.setNavigationIcon(), Toolbar will dynamically add or remove navigation view depending on specified value

```
public void setNavigationIcon(@Nullable Drawable icon) {
    if (icon != null) {
        ensureNavButtonView();
        if (!isChildOrHidden(mNavButtonView)) {
            addSystemView(mNavButtonView, true);
        }
    } else if (mNavButtonView != null && isChildOrHidden(mNavButtonView)) {
        removeView(mNavButtonView);
        mHiddenViews.remove(mNavButtonView);
    }
    if (mNavButtonView != null) {
        mNavButtonView.setImageDrawable(icon);
    }
}
```

And in onLayout it will check whether navigation button is present and lay it out.

```
protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int l, int t, int r, int b) {

    // more code before

    if (shouldLayout(mNavButtonView)) {
        if (isRtl) {
            right = layoutChildRight(mNavButtonView, right, collapsingMargins,
                    alignmentHeight);
        } else {
            left = layoutChildLeft(mNavButtonView, left, collapsingMargins,
                    alignmentHeight);
        }
    }

    // more code after. also mTitleTextView is laid out here
}
```

Toolbar also increments left/right position after laying out each view. These values used as an offset for each subsequent view.

To check whether view should be laid out it uses helper function:

```
private boolean shouldLayout(View view) {
    return view != null && view.getParent() == this && view.getVisibility() != GONE;
}
```

### The Problem

When setting layoutTransition through the code or animateLayoutChanges in the xml we change behaviour a little bit.

Lets start with what happening when we remove child from parent (ViewGroup code):

```
private void removeFromArray(int index) {
    final View[] children = mChildren;
    if (!(mTransitioningViews != null && mTransitioningViews.contains(children[index]))) {
        children[index].mParent = null;
    }

    // more code after
}
```

Did you mention that child's parent is not nulled when we have transition set? This is important!

Also please recall what shouldLayout from above does - it checks for only three cases:

1. view is not null
2. view's parent is toolbar
3. view is not GONE

And here is the root of the problem - navigation button is removed from the toolbar but it doesn't event know about this.

### The Solution

In order to fix this problem we need to force toolbar into thinking that view shouldn't be laid out. Ideally it would be nice to override shouldLayout method but we don't have such luxury... So the only way we can accomplish this is by changing visibility on the navigation button.

```
class FixedToolbar(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet?) : MaterialToolbar(context, attrs) {
    companion object {
        private val navButtonViewField = Toolbar::class.java.getDeclaredField("mNavButtonView")
                .also { it.isAccessible = true }
    }

    override fun setNavigationIcon(icon: Drawable?) {
        super.setNavigationIcon(icon)

        (navButtonViewField.get(this) as? View)?.isGone = (icon == null)
    }
}
```

Now toolbar will know that navigation button must not be laid out and all animations will go as intended.

Comment: Only solution I found on the web that works, nice! Any solution without reflection possible?

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround to get the transition to work.

After calling `supportActionBar?.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false)` to hide the back arrow button, call the [TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/transition/TransitionManager.html#beginDelayedTransition(android.view.ViewGroup)) method to trigger the transition manually.

```
// Hide the back arrow button
supportActionBar?.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false)
// Add a transition listener to the toolbar to set the toolbar title later
mToolbar.layoutTransition.addTransitionListener(object : LayoutTransition.TransitionListener {
    override fun startTransition(transition: LayoutTransition?, container: ViewGroup?, view: View?, transitionType: Int) {}

    override fun endTransition(transition: LayoutTransition?, container: ViewGroup?, view: View?, transitionType: Int) {
        setToolbarTitle("Agenda")
        mToolbar.layoutTransition.removeTransitionListener(this)
    }
})

TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition(mToolbar)
```

### BEFORE

[image]

### AFTER

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Even with this questions more than a year back, this issue is still happening with the version `androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:2.4.2`

According to @MatrixDev, yes, this is still the final solution is:

```
class FixedToolbar(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet?) : MaterialToolbar(context, attrs) {
    companion object {
        private val navButtonViewField = Toolbar::class.java.getDeclaredField("mNavButtonView")
            .also { it.isAccessible = true }
    }

    override fun setNavigationIcon(icon: Drawable?) {
        super.setNavigationIcon(icon)
        (navButtonViewField.get(this) as? View)?.isGone = (icon == null)
    }
}
```